# Hide default "Recent Comments" Widget if there are no comments yet

Tags: themes, widgets, comments

Is there a way to hide the widget completely if there are no comments yet?

I was thinking about maybe adding a php function to my functions.php file - is that a possible way? If so, can someone provide a suggestion?

Comment: You'd better make your own extend of Widget Class for this

Comment: I haven't had time to test it yet, but I think Wyck's answer would be the solution. I'll mark the answer as soon as I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a hook for the comment widget but you can call a widget in your template with a conditional to check if there are comments. You can probably also do this via functions.php.

Something like:

```
$num_comments = get_comments_number();

if ( $num_comments > 0 ) {  
    the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Comments' );
} else { 
 // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea using the [`sidebars_widgets`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/widgets.php#L1249) filter from the `wp_get_sidebars_widgets()` function that's [called](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/widgets.php#L972) within the `dynamic_sidebar()` function:

```
/** 
 * Remove the recent comments widgets from a given sidebar (index)
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/151361/26350
 */
! is_admin() && add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', function( $sidebars_widgets ) {

    // ------------------------
    // Edit this to your needs:
    $sidebar_index = 'sidebar-1';
    $find          = 'recent-comments';
    // ------------------------

    if( isset( $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_index] ) && 0 == get_comments_number() )
    {
        foreach( $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_index] as $key => $widget )
        {
            if( false !== stripos( $widget, $find ) )
                 unset( $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_index][$key] );

        }
    }
    return $sidebars_widgets;
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

where you must remember to modify the `$sidebar_index` and `$find` to your needs.

We could also loop over all the sidebars, instead of  targetting a single sidebar. I'm sure you can adjust the code snippet if you need that.